# Loading dojo patch files when running intern test

Tags: dojo, intern

With dojo, patch files can be created and loaded via 'patches/patch!' where patch.js contains load function with all patches.

Content patch.js

```
define(['require'], function(require) {
    return {
       load: function load(id, parentRequire, loaderCallback) {
         require([< patch files >], loaderCallback);
       }
     };
});
```

When running intern suites I want that those patches are also loaded first before running my suites.
Is there a way to ensure that my patch files are loaded before running my test suites.

Regards Marco

Answer (score 0):

When you define your tests suite, you have a before function where you can call your load patch function

```
define(["intern!tdd", "patch"], function (tdd, patch) {
    tdd.describe("Tests suite", function () {
        tdd.before(function () {
            // executes before suite starts
            patch.load();
        });
    });
});
```